# How to refresh local IP address?

Tags: ssh, ip

How to refresh my current local IP address as seen on `ip a` command near `inet`?
The problem is that sometimes I'm connecting a cable from a switch and then the IP changes.

It seem to change because whenever I connect it to the switch I can't ssh anymore (timed out)

*The switch is actually and old router I'm using as a switch

Answer (score 0):

Forget the IP use `ssh user_name@host_name.local` to connect to the machine named `host_name`. It will solve your IP changing problem.

```
MacUser2525:~$ alias pi
alias pi='ssh zeus@buster-raspi.local'
MacUser2525:~$ pi
Linux buster-raspi 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 (2020-12-31) aarch64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Feb 18 01:31:30 2021 from fe80::1003:5492:80fa:2bc5%eth0
zeus@buster-raspi:~$
```